# How to identify PCI device failing in Ubuntu 20.04 and how to know if it is broken hardware

Tags: dell, pcie

My network Dell laptop WiFi connection started failing suddenly, and I found the following messages in `dmesg`  not sure if related, I can't find the device id with `lspci`. How can I find it, and should I be worried hardware is broken?

```
[260319.955706] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, (Transmitter ID)
[260319.955717] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00001000/00002000
[260319.955724] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER:    [12] Timeout
```

`lspci` shows the device is the WiFi card. This was not happening with 16.04, but the sound was not working. With 20.04 fully updated + BIOS update the sound works but I'm getting this error all the time.

```
 +-1c.4-[3a]----00.0  Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
```

Comment: The vendor:device for 8086:9d14 is Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5, so it appears the complaint is from the PCIe bus controller itself. You'll need to google debugging of a WiFi device... this will give you the commands to get correct ID's and stats to check. A data error could be cause by a bad connection on the motherboard, where the WiFi device sits in its slot. Depending on the laptop, the device may sit under an easy-access cover, so removing, cleaning device and slot, and then re-seating could fix it?

Comment: You're getting AER errors. Probably from a wireless device. There may be a workaround. What version Ubuntu? Is it up to date with Software Updates? Edit your question and show me `sudo lspci -tv` and `sudo lspci -knn`.