# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS - power off button wont work

Tags: gnome, power-management, shutdown

I have 20.04.3 upgraded from 20.04.1 and problem still exists:

When i click "power off" > "power off" > and confirm, after pressing the button the shutdown procedure don't start - i can wait and nothing. Next i click again power off and confirm and later it works and shutdown correctly.

The problem does not occur often, rather 2-3 times (out of 7) a week.

I looked for this issue but didnt find the same problem.

EDIT (add logs):

```
Sep  2 12:40:41 pw systemd[1]: Starting Ubuntu Advantage APT and MOTD Messages...
Sep  2 12:40:42 pw systemd[1]: ua-messaging.service: Succeeded.
Sep  2 12:40:42 pw systemd[1]: Finished Ubuntu Advantage APT and MOTD Messages.
Sep  2 12:42:25 pw kernel: [ 2921.326768] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.4
Sep  2 12:42:25 pw kernel: [ 2921.326781] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Sep  2 12:42:25 pw kernel: [ 2921.326783] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Sep  2 12:42:25 pw kernel: [ 2921.326784] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Sep  2 12:42:31 pw kernel: [ 2927.324405] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.4
Sep  2 12:42:31 pw kernel: [ 2927.324415] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Sep  2 12:42:31 pw kernel: [ 2927.324417] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Sep  2 12:42:31 pw kernel: [ 2927.324419] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Sep  2 12:42:43 pw kernel: [ 2939.325035] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.4
Sep  2 12:42:43 pw kernel: [ 2939.325053] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Sep  2 12:42:43 pw kernel: [ 2939.325055] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Sep  2 12:42:43 pw kernel: [ 2939.325059] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Sep  2 12:42:55 pw kernel: [ 2951.323854] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.4
Sep  2 12:42:55 pw kernel: [ 2951.323886] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Sep  2 12:42:55 pw kernel: [ 2951.323895] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Sep  2 12:42:55 pw kernel: [ 2951.323906] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Sep  2 12:43:01 pw kernel: [ 2957.322915] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.4
Sep  2 12:43:01 pw kernel: [ 2957.322940] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Sep  2 12:43:01 pw kernel: [ 2957.322946] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Sep  2 12:43:01 pw kernel: [ 2957.322953] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:    [ 0] RxErr                 
Sep  2 12:43:04 pw gnome-shell[2833]: ../clutter/clutter/clutter-actor.c:10558: The clutter_actor_set_allocation() function can only be called from within the implementation of the ClutterActor::allocate() virtual function.
Sep  2 12:43:07 pw dbus-daemon[1290]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' unit='packagekit.service' requested by ':1.85' (uid=1000 pid=2833 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Sep  2 12:43:07 pw systemd[1]: Starting PackageKit Daemon...
Sep  2 12:43:07 pw PackageKit: daemon start
Sep  2 12:43:07 pw dbus-daemon[1290]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
Sep  2 12:43:07 pw systemd[1]: Started PackageKit Daemon.
Sep  2 12:43:07 pw gnome-shell[2833]: endSessionDialog: No XDG_SESSION_ID, fetched from logind: 2
Sep  2 12:43:08 pw gnome-session[2819]: gnome-session-binary[2819]: WARNING: Client '/org/gnome/SessionManager/Client25' failed to reply before timeout
Sep  2 12:43:08 pw gnome-session-binary[2819]: WARNING: Client '/org/gnome/SessionManager/Client25' failed to reply before timeout
Sep  2 12:43:08 pw gnome-shell[2833]: endSessionDialog: No XDG_SESSION_ID, fetched from logind: 2
Sep  2 12:43:10 pw systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service: Succeeded.
Sep  2 12:43:19 pw systemd[2560]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Sep  2 12:43:19 pw dbus-daemon[2571]: [session uid=1000 pid=2571] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.214' (uid=1000 pid=6243 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real --window " label="unconfined")
Sep  2 12:43:19 pw systemd[2560]: Created slice apps.slice.
Sep  2 12:43:19 pw systemd[2560]: Created slice apps-org.gnome.Terminal.slice.
Sep  2 12:43:19 pw systemd[2560]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Sep  2 12:43:19 pw dbus-daemon[2571]: [session uid=1000 pid=2571] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Sep  2 12:43:19 pw systemd[2560]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Sep  2 12:43:19 pw at-spi-bus-launcher[2807]: dbus-daemon[2807]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry' requested by ':1.23' (uid=1000 pid=6246 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server " label="unconfined")
Sep  2 12:43:19 pw at-spi-bus-launcher[2807]: dbus-daemon[2807]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Sep  2 12:43:19 pw at-spi-bus-launcher[6251]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Sep  2 12:43:20 pw systemd[2560]: Started VTE child process 6258 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 6246.
Sep  2 12:43:20 pw systemd[2560]: gnome-launched-org.gnome.Terminal.desktop-6242.scope: Succeeded.
Sep  2 12:43:31 pw kernel: [ 2987.324521] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.4
Sep  2 12:43:31 pw kernel: [ 2987.324547] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Sep  2 12:43:31 pw kernel: [ 2987.324553] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:   device [8086:9d14] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Sep  2 12:43:31 pw kernel: [ 2987.324560] pcieport 0000:00:1c.4:    [ 0] RxErr
```

Comment: Do you see shy messages in your `/var/log/syslog` file that might explain why the system isn’t shutting down? There are lots of reasons why a machine might take a really long time to power off or reboot 

Comment: i'll check log when error occurs again, thanks

Comment: i added logs with errors (/var/log/syslog)

Comment: The `8086:9d14` is a controller on the motherboard and, based on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1263295/1222991) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1284741/1222991), a kernel update is usually the solution. That said, if you’ve just upgraded to 20.04.3, then you’re at the most recent stable 

Comment: thanks, what a pity :/